# Single query to update the flag in all the child tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to update a flag in all the child tables based on the id which is a primary key in master table. I want to do it in single query how can I do it??

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE with according JOINs and according SET expressions amount.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support multi-table update statements. If you want a single statement then use PL/SQL to wrap multiple SQL single-table update statements:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_id MAIN_TABLE.ID%TYPE := 1;
BEGIN
  UPDATE child_table1
  SET    flag = 1
  WHERE  id = v_id;

  UPDATE child_table2
  SET    flag = 1
  WHERE  id = v_id;

  UPDATE child_table2
  SET    flag = 1
  WHERE  id = v_id;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE main
JOIN slave1 USING (id)
JOIN slave2 USING (id)
...
SET slave1.flag = 1,
    slave2.flag = 1,
...
WHERE main.id IN ( {ids list} )
...
```

Comment: This is not working in sql developer when I use join after after update main it is throwing me an error.

Comment: AFAIR the question was tagged as MySQL-relative. The answer uses MySQL syntax.

Comment: Sorry for that I re tagged the question now. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: @MohammadGouse AFAIR Oracle does not support multiple-table (subquery or view) UPDATE for a table on the side "many"... but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join with sub query may helpful
Example:

> UPDATE Students
> SET flag = true
> WHERE id in (SELECT student.id from Students
> INNER JOIN Classes
> on students.classId = classes.id
> );

Comment: I don't want to update the master table I want to update the flag in child tables with a single query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).